# Missing keymaps "Windows proper redo" flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, keymapping

I'm getting this error in event log:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVnoq.png)

How can I fix this.?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the actual solution but my error was gone after taking the following steps:

1. Go to `File ->Settings ->Keymap -> <Choose Eclipse from Keymaps dropdown>` and Restart IDE
2. Again change keymap to Windows
   `File ->Settings ->Keymap -> <Choose Windows again from Keymaps dropdown>` and Restart IDE

It's work for me.